# Guardar una imagen en base 64 desde URL

Tags: genexus, blob, base64

En Genexus15, no puedo guardar una imagen desde una URL para pasarla a base 64.

```
&image.ImageURI = 'unaURLCualquiera'
&url = &image.ImageURI
&blob.FromString(&url)
&blob.ToBase64String()
```

Comment: De que tipo es &image? y cual es el error del output que tienes?

Comment: &image es de tipo image (Default de Genexus). Soy un novato en Genexus y estoy probando, realmente no sé si mi método es correcto. Me gustaría saber si tu conoces una forma. Y tampoco tengo errores en el output. :)

Comment: Ok, pero cual es el fin!? o únicamente lo que necesitas es pasarlo a base64? y por qué?

Comment: En el área de marketing va  a publicar fotos en una cuenta de OneDrive y yo los voy a enviar como servicio web. Este servicio web no está en https y queremos agregarle un base 64 (me queda claro que no la estoy codificando) pero es una forma de no mandar la información en bruto.

Comment: Entiendo, déjame ver como te ayudo.

Comment: Mm vas a alimentar un web service, que protocolo usa SOAP o REST? otra duda, la imagen la obtienes de tu base de datos o estas consumiendo otro web service?

Answer (score 1):

La forma de convertir una imagen a un *string* en base 64 es mediante un `Blob` como estás haciendo, pero el problema es la forma en que se carga el `Blob`.

No hay forma de asignar una variable de tipo `Blob` en memoria, el `Blob` se tiene que cargar desde el *file system*. Una posible solución es guardar la imagen en un directorio temporal y cargarla en el `Blob` usando el método `FromString`.

Con este código logré hacer que funcione:

```
Event 'ToBase64'
    &httpclient.Execute('GET', &image.ImageURI)
    &tmpFile = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + 'temp.png'
    &httpclient.ToFile(&tmpFile)
    &blob.FromString(&tmpFile)
    &base64Str = &blob.ToBase64String()
Endevent
```

donde:

- `&image` es de tipo `Image`,
- `&httpclient` es de tipo `HttpClient`,
- `&tmpFile` es de tipo `VarChar`,
- `&blob` es de tipo `Blob`, y
- `&base64Str` es de tipo `LongVarChar`

Answer (score 0):

Encontré un [enlace](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7374,Blobs%20in%20Base64,) de la documentación de Genexus mismo, donde puedes obtener o generar un archivo Blob en base64:

- ToBase64String (): Devuelve el contenido del archivo Blob en Base64.
- FromBase64String (): carga el contenido en Base64 recibida por los parámetros en el archivo Blob.

Y lo usas de la siguiente forma:

```
ContentBase64 = <att | var>.ToBase64String()
<att | var>.FromBase64String(ContentBase64)
```

ContentBase64 contiene el Base64 y podria ser un LongVarChar, por ejemplo.

Hasta ahora, cuando un servicio Web con un parámetro de Blob que retorna es llamado, el valor devuelto será el archivo Blob en Base64.

```
ContentBase64 = WebServiceBlob.Execute()
```

Espero te sirva mi pequeña ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Rostan por tu rápida respuesta, precisamente estoy usando en el código &blob.ToBase64String(), pero lo que parece que no estoy realizando correctamente es cargar desde una URL la imagen en una variable tipo blob :C

Yo esperaría poder hacerlo con la siguiente línea pero no funciona:
&blob.FromString("http://compania.com/galeria/imagen1.png")

Sin embargo no funciona

Comment: Mm vas a alimentar un web service, que protocolo usa SOAP o REST? otra duda, la imagen la obtienes de tu base de datos o estas consumiendo otro web service? Disculpa lo puse como respuesta.

Comment: No puedes bajarlo desde la url a un archivo temporal en el file system, y de ahí cargar el blob?